# Custom range angular directive with events

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create an range directive to repeat the included html x times. 
Like this:

```
...
.directive('raichuRange', function () {
    return{
        scope:{
            range: '=raichuRange'
        },
        transclude: 'element',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn){
            var parent = element.parent();
            for(var i = 1;i<= scope.range;++i){
                var childScope = scope.$new();
                childScope.$index = i;
                transcludeFn(childScope, function (clone) {
                    parent.append(clone);
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The problem with this is: any ng-click directives within don't respond anymore.

Comment: The `ng-click` directives worked for me in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqh89mcu/).

Comment: Thanks for trying it. It's weird. I also tried someone elses code for a similar directive, and it had the same problem. I used ng-repeat, and I didn't. Something else must be broken then.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? https://jsfiddle.net/pq1wkp90/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work? https://jsfiddle.net/pq1wkp90/

Because the directive uses an **isolate scope**, the parent functions are not inherited by the directive scope or their children.

To access the functions on the parent scope of the directive use:

```
ng-click="$parent.$parent.test($index)"
```

Use one `$parent` to access the isolate scope from the transcluded element. The second `$parent` to access the parent of the isolate scope.

For more information on directive scopes, [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

---

PS. Also change `$scope.$index = $index + 1;` to `$scope.$index = $scope.$index + 1;`

Comment: PSS. `ng-repeat` doesn't use **isolate scope**. You might want to change your directive to use `scope: false` and use `scope.$eval(attrs.range)` to evaluate the `range` attribute.